# Django problems with database

Tags: django, postgresql

Hello I'm getting problems with my Django db.

this is my settings.py

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'MConDb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'KODOkona880,',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "MConDb" does not exist
```

and this is the list shown by the command \l in postgres

```
         Name         |  Owner   | Encoding |          Collate           |           Ctype            |   Access privileges
----------------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+---
 django               | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 mcondb               | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
 postgres             | postgres | UTF8     | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 |
```

hope you could help me, I'll be very grateful thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database name is in all small letters `mcondb | postgr..` , then why are you using `'NAME': 'MConDb'`

Try this :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mcondb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'KODOkona880,',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Are you sure your password contains a `,` at end ? Please verify that.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem, I wrote the database like that using uppercase letters but it automatically set the database to lowercase, I tried changing the database name in my settings.py to lowercase letters and that's it. Have a nice day.